# How to loop through non-sequential array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this :

```
Array
{
[1] => test
[3] => some
[7] => thing
[444] => like
[777] => this
}
```

It is not Sorted.

How can i access to every every elements in foreach OR for loop ?

I need to have and echo them with having aLL in one variable like this :

```
echo $value; // echo out : testsomethinglikethis
```

Comment: Oh, how can I access thee, let me count the ways: implode(), foreach(), array_keys(), array_values(), array_column().... just a few suggestions

Comment: @MarkBaker Can u please give code with foreach ? tnx.

Comment: `foreach($myArray as $value) { echo $value; }` perhaps a few hours just reading what the manual says about arrays would help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use implode like

```
echo implode("", $your_array);
```

**Method:2:** foreach

```
$value = "";
foreach($your_array as $val)
{
   $value .= $val;
}

echo $value;
```

Comment: as i said , i want to have them In **One** variable.